# Power BI: Measure to calculate the first and final yield by product and file name

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a measure to calculate the first and final pass yield of a product under the respective file name.

This is a sample of my test data. In this case, each file name (ex: File_111) will test 3 same product - P1, P2, P3.
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClE6g.png)

By right, the result of the **first-pass yield** should be:

1. File_111 - Pass, Fail, Pass (66.67%)
2. File_211 - Pass, Fail, Fail (33.33%)
3. File_311 - Pass, Pass, Pass (100%)

However, I followed one of the examples and used the following codes, but the first pass yield is wrong for scenario 2.

```
    FPYield = 
    VAR distinctCountTotal = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sheet1'[Product Number]))
    VAR distinctCountFail = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sheet1'[Result]),'Sheet1'[Result] = "Fail")
    RETURN 
    DIVIDE(distinctCountTotal - distinctCountFail, distinctCountTotal)
```

As shown, for scenario 2, the first yield is 66.67% when it should be 33.33%. I couldn't figure out what is the mistake made. For scenario 3, it shows the correct one which is 100%.

[Scenario-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVqIJ.png)
[Scenario-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcvjd.png)

Things to consider:

1. Should be able to filter average FPY by either File Name or Product Number (Take product number as my tester, there will only be 3 - P1, P2, P3

Followed up, I also need to calculate the final pass yield if all the product numbers in that file passed in the last run. What dax measure should I put to take the last status of the run? Thanks!

**Edit:** 
Any suggestion on how I can calculate for final pass yield if I have a DateTime column in my dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Distinct Count of Product number in both the cases:

```
FPYield = 
    VAR distinctCountTotal = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sheet1'[Product Number]))
    VAR distinctCountFail = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Product Number]),'Sheet1'[Result] = "Fail")
    RETURN 
    DIVIDE(distinctCountTotal - distinctCountFail, distinctCountTotal)
```

To get the last status of a product number, you need to use a date variable available in your data. If there are no date variables available, then you would have to create an index column in your base query to do this. Once you have a date/index variable, then you can get the result for the latest date or the highest index.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works! Many thanks. Assuming I have a date column in my data set, what measure can I use to order/sort by latest date (without using Power Query or creating a new column) with the similar measure for the first pass yield.